# Formatting of DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString

Tags: android

I have code like this

```
DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(context, due, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS,0)
```

which is outputting strings formatted like

```
in 23 hours, 6:18am
```

I don't understand well the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29) on this method.

Is there a built in way to strip off the time or change the comma to be more sentence like?

Either of "in 23 hours"  or "in 23 hours at 6:18am" would be preferable to the current output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have used a different method and gotten the "in 23 hours" result I wanted

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(due,now, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you would have to implement the functionality of DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS yourself

Answer (score 1):

According to Android Documentation, you'll need to add a flag to display "42 mins ago", instead of "42 mins ago 01/01/2020".

```kotlin
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
    item.createdAt.time,
    Date().time,
    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
    FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE
)
```

> Can use FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE flag to use abbreviated relative times, like "42 mins ago".

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long,%20int)