# Date Conversion Date is a Variable String

Tags: android

I have a variable which holds a date as a String in the format of dd/MM/yyyy, I want to convert that to milliseconds or some format so I can count days.

The date String has come from a MYSQLite DB, It was saved to the DB as a String using

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
```

What I'm trying to do is count the days from date data was inputed till now
I have queried the DB and have the date as a variable but its a String...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to convert string dat to `Date` object:

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    //calculate the difference in days here
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this below code

```
String someDate = "29-09-2014";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(someDate);
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Comment: The issue I have here is my date is stored in a variable, so where you have 29-09-2014 I have a Variable dateSelected which has come from a MYSQLite DataBase query, that query output all date in DB to a listView and stores the selected date to a Variable called dateSelected

Comment: u just call the dataSelected string variable like this Date date = sdf.parse(dateSelected);

Answer (score 0):

DateUtils in java provides a method called getRelativeDateTimeString() to do this.

[Formatting of DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045249/formatting-of-dateutils-getrelativedatetimestring)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long stringToDateMillis(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try{
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(date).getTime();
    }catch (ParseException e){
        Log.e("Util", "Cannot parse date");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(year, Month, day, 
         0, 0, 0);
 long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

this is the time stored in db.

```
 long endtime = System.currentmilliseconds();

 long remain= endtime-starttime;
```

then calculate number of days from remain(milliseconds).